# Cannot Change Root Passwd

Tags: root, ubuntu-10.04, passwd

I know there have been a lot of posts about this, but cannot seem to find an answer that has worked for me.

I wanted to change the password of my root user, but have failed in doing so.

logged in as root;
root@ubuntu:/ passwd

passwd: Permission denied

passwd: password unchanged

root@ubuntu:/ sudo passwd root
passwd: Permission denied;;
passwd: password unchanged;;

this is a ubuntu 10.04 system and i dont know how can i solve this.
I have tried changing the PAM files as well as login.defs file,but to no avail. can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo passwd root
```

Now u see it asking for the new password for root. So reset it and Enjoy :)

```
$su root
```

Give the new password that you have entered

Answer (score 0):

Enter recovery mode through grub and choose to enter a root shell. From there:

```
passwd <user>
```

No unmounting of the drive is required.

Comment: I cannot afford to unmount the drive, as it runs critical applications for the Website.

Comment: yes, i am. Sudo works fine with everything. but, not when i want to change the password of the root user

Comment: What are the permissions of `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow`?

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1466 2013-06-09 23:04 /etc/passwd
###
-rw-r----- 1 root root  986 2013-06-09 23:04 /etc/shadow

Comment: If changing the root password isn't time-critical, maybe just schedule server downtime and [unmount the drive](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password/24024#24024)? Not a solution, I know, but still...

Comment: as the server is linked to a lot of company web servers, it is not feasible to unmount the drive. And changing the password is time critical for me right now.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your /etc/pam.d/common-password looks like this

```
# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
password        [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so obscure sha512
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
password        requisite                       pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
password        required                        pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
# end of pam-auth-update config
```